# TypeORM Datasource Connection Options: How to use autoSaveCallback with sqljs database?

Tags: javascript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I need to save my database every hour, but autoSaveCallback is are'nt good documented in the docs: https://typeorm.io/data-source-options#sqljs-data-source-options

How to use this option? I don't finded any examples on the docs. Can anyone give me example? Thanks for reply in advance.[Screenshot of my datasource options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elT6z.png)